# Protractor - How to use multi filters to find out the target row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

I want to filter out the target row which contains the specific text in the cell of cells belong to this row.

Here is my code:

```
 private selectTargetLicense(licenseName: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve => {
      element.all(by.tagName('clr-dg-table-wrapper')).first().all(by.tagName('clr-dg-row')).filter(function (row_element) {
        return row_element.all(by.tagName('clr-dg-cell')).filter(function (cell) {
          return cell.getWebElement().getText().then(function (text) {
            return text.trim() === licenseName;
          })
        })
      }).first().getWebElement().click().then(() => {
        resolve();
      })
    }))
  }
```

It not works as what I think that failed to get the target row from the rows in the table.

So how should I use the multi filter correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to investigate your code without HTML code. Could you show it us?

Do you want to click a cell with given text or entire row?

Code for clicking the cell:

```
private selectTargetLicense(licenseName: string) {
const rows = element.all(by.css('clr-dg-table-wrapper:nth-of-type(1) clr-dg-row clr-dg-cell'));
return rows.filter((row_element) => {
    return row_element.getText().then((text) => {
        return text.trim() === licenseName;
    });
}).first().click();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your help. row_element.getText()  this rescued me.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use nested `filter`, filter on rows is sufficient.

```
private selectTargetLicense(licenseName: string) {

    const rows = element(by.css('clr-dg-table-wrapper')).all(by.css('clr-dg-row'));

    rows.filter((row) => {

        // read text of all cells of one row into array: txts
        return row.all(by.css('clr-dg-cell')).getText().then((txts) => {

            return txts.map((it)=>{
                        // trim each text
                        return it.trim();
                   })
                   // use array.includes() to detect row contains specified licenseName
                   .includes(licenseName);
        });
    })
    .first()
    .click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yong. Very helpful.  I tried this with some refactor and it works. One tip, string not support map directly. so I changed there.